# Will unused Usings/Imports affect performance on a webpage if the code isn't compiled?

Tags: .net

I've found answers saying it will only affect compiling time. However if a webpage isn't compiled, would there be a performance difference during use?

Comment: Well, if you don't pre-compile your site, it would have an affect.  It could not be a noticeable effect though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unused using have a negligible performance impact on compilation times and zero impact on run time. This question is moot.

Still, to answer it completely: If a webpage is never compiled, unused using have no impact. If a webpage is compiled (on first use, or as part of precompilation) you'll probably pay a few milliseconds once.

Never do unused using affect run time. They are not baked into the binary.